# Changing JSPX file inside an EAR file

Tags: edit, ear, jdeveloper, jspx

Since I do not have the source code for my production site that is deployed as an EAR file, I need to make a small change in one JSPX file inside the EAR file. I open the EAR in 7-ZIP, edit the JSPX and deploy the same. The change is not reflecting in the site. Is there anything else to be done to make the change reflect?

Comment: Can you please be specific about what kind of change you made in the JSPX? In theory, this should work depending on the change. Are you sure the previous app was undeployed/overwritten? Also note that javascript may be previously cached in the browser.

Comment: I added an if-else conditional statement in the JSPX file. This piece of code works fine when an EAR is built and deployed but when the same change is added to the existing EAR file the else part of the condition is executed always. As for the previous installation, I uninstalled it in the weblogic server, cleared all the old folders and deployed again. I did clear the cache after deploying.

Comment: Would that be an expression language if-else, or javascript if-else? It wouldn't hurt to put in some random ui text to ensure at least that is displayed after the change. If it is, then you would have to suspect if-else linkage issue.